# Calculated Property to display multiple service status not working?

Tags: powershell

I wonder how to correct the below calculated property line:

```
@{ n = 'DFS Service Status'; e = { (Get-Service -Name DFS* -ComputerName $ENV:ComputerName | FL ) } },
```

The result is:

```
DFS Service Status
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupEndData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData
```

Comment: What are you expecting the output to be? Just if the service is running?

Comment: Replace `... | FL` with `... |Select -Expand Status`

Comment: Too much guessing, please create a [mcve], see also: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Yes, I'd like to get the ‘DisplayName - Status’, ‘DisplayName - Status’, ...

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer As a string? Or do you want objects with those two properties?

Comment: Just the string as I wanted to Convert-HTML And send as email.

Comment: You definitely don't want to pipe raw strings to `ConvertTo-HTML`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From OPs comments:

> I'd like to get the ‘DisplayName - Status’, ‘DisplayName - Status’ [...] as I wanted to Convert-HTML And send as email.

With this in mind, you'll want to retain the properties of the input object and then let `ConvertTo-Html` handle the "stringification" of the property values:

```
# ConvertTo-Html will inspect the input objects and use the `DisplayName` and `Status` 
# properties as column values in the HTML table
$html = Get-Service -Name DFS* |ConvertTo-Html -Property DisplayName,Status -Title "DFS Service Status" -As Table

# ...

Send-MailMessage ... -Body $html -BodyAsHtml
```

Comment: Thanks man ! I appreciate your assitance in this matter.